# Application with AAD App Id is not authorized to generate notifications about [...] to the recipient

Tags: c#, notifications, microsoft-graph-api, postman, microsoft-teams

Good morning,
I'm trying to use the Microsoft graph's API to send notifications in Microsoft Teams feed.

I've created a C# APP and gave all Authorization following the official Guide:
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

But I couldn't get the things done. So I've chosen to make things a little bit easier by cutting out the whole C# App using only Postman. The result is that I get the same error...

**(ATTEMPT 1 WITH POSTMAN)** -> This is the body of my request:

```json
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{MY_USER_ID}/teamwork/installedApps/{APP_ID}"
    },
    "activityType": "taskCreated",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "New Task Created"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "taskId",
            "value": "Task 12322"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/beta/users/{MY_USER_ID}/teamwork/microsoft.graph.sendActivityNotification
```

As result I get this:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Application with AAD App Id '{APP_ID}' is not authorized to generate notifications about 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{MY_USER_ID}/teamwork/installedApps/{APP_ID}' to the recipient.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "{date}",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-request-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

**(ATTEMPT 2 WITH POSTMAN)** -> This is the body of my request (which is the same as the 1st one):

```json
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{MY_USER_ID}/teamwork/installedApps/{APP_ID}"
    },
    "activityType": "taskCreated",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "New Task Created"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "taskId",
            "value": "Task 12322"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my call (the things which change):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{MY_USER_ID}/teamwork/installedApps/{APP_ID}
```

and this is the error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "{date}",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-request-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

I think the right call is the first one, but I'm not sure...
I've already given the permission required by the guide I've linked above (TeamsActivity.Send 'delegated' and TeamsActivity.Send 'application').

I'm sure I'm missing something but from [GraphExplorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I can't even test the right call/understand which permission I'm missing

Thanks in advance,
Giovanni

**---------EDIT 1---------**

As requested by Carl Zhao here my Access token, I had to censor some data but I think It will readable in the same way:

```json
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "nonce": "FHxXnlAuHU14c4czPflNLrniH-4d-4ZdRNawgEx6LQg",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
    "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg"
}.{
    "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/9e892716-96e0-4bf4-a58a-e43212bfab33/",
    "iat": 1614156685,
    "nbf": 1614156685,
    "exp": 1614160585,
    "acct": 0,
    "acr": "1",
    "acrs": [
        "urn:user:registersecurityinfo",
        "urn:microsoft:req1",
        "urn:microsoft:req2",
        "urn:microsoft:req3",
        "c1",
        "c2",
        "c3",
        "c4",
        "c5",
        "c6",
        "c7",
        "c8",
        "c9",
        "c10",
        "c11",
        "c12",
        "c13",
        "c14",
        "c15",
        "c16",
        "c17",
        "c18",
        "c19",
        "c20",
        "c21",
        "c22",
        "c23",
        "c24",
        "c25"
    ],
    "aio": "E2ZgYBBXWFm5tc8nMm5J68RHD6qmJ31f8GpGeqzcg8/+XlvTE40B",
    "amr": [
        "pwd"
    ],
    "app_displayname": "NotificationSender",
    "appid": "{APP_ID}",
    "appidacr": "0",
    "family_name": "{My_surname}",
    "given_name": "{My_name}",
    "idtyp": "user",
    "ipaddr": "{IP}",
    "name": "{My_surname} {My_name}",
    "oid": "{MY_USER_ID}",
    "platf": "14",
    "puid": "10032001002D8362",
    "rh": "0.AREAFieJnuCW9EuliuQyEr-rM44Tv1nRFotKsOAymqy2XUwRALk.",
    "scp": "email IdentityProvider.Read.All IdentityProvider.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All IdentityRiskEvent.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskyUser.Read.All IdentityRiskyUser.ReadWrite.All IdentityUserFlow.Read.All IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All Notifications.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp openid profile TeamsActivity.Read TeamsActivity.Send TeamsApp.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All UserNotification.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp",
    "sub": "EmlIIgfTtCx92uXpG26JS3A4s30BF-L_q08y7WpK45g",
    "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
    "tid": "9e892716-96e0-4bf4-a58a-e43212bfab33",
    "unique_name": "{My_Mail}",
    "upn": "{My_Mail}",
    "uti": "hfEx4TU7lEOdFnLyO38VAA",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "wids": [
        "7be44c8a-adaf-4e2a-84d6-ab2649e08a13",
        "158c047a-c907-4556-b7ef-446551a6b5f7",
        "baf37b3a-610e-45da-9e62-d9d1e5e8914b",
        "c4e39bd9-1100-46d3-8c65-fb160da0071f",
        "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3",
        "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"
    ],
    "xms_st": {
        "sub": "xFCFf1A82XccwsRgTd7olVqOBVUE9pZ5d6QDyWjbojc"
    },
    "xms_tcdt": 1428499913
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: I've added the parsed access token. I was reading the documentation and I saw that in faqs is mentioned that I cant send myself a notification... I've already tried to send it to a colleague and it didn't work either...

Comment: Any progress on this? We are facing exactly the same issue

Comment: unfortunately no but I've asked directly to Microsoft and I'm waiting for their response at this URL: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/297037/teams-send-notification-in-feed-400-bad-request.html)

Comment: I'm also have the exact same error: "Application with AAD App Id 'd51d7ecb-bc5f-49a7-81ef-04837ef4470b' is not authorized to generate notifications about 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/teamwork/installedApps/[installationid]' to the recipient. Ensure that the expected Teams app is installed in the target scope (user, team, or chat).". Tried several things, but no luck. Was anyone able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I have to post this as an answer since I don't have enough rep to comment.  More of a guide than an answer.

Prerequisite: Your C# app is registered in Azure, with Graph API permissions for TeamsActivity.Send

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

1. Using the Teams ["Developer Portal"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/teams-developer-portal) app, I went to the "apps" tab and added a new app.  Under "app features", I added an activity feed notification, and then I published as an app package (to upload as an org app later, you'll see why in the next step).
2. For some reason the app (client) id I entered in the previous step did not get put into my manifest file (maybe because I didn't add an SSO provider?  I'm not sure).  So I modified the teams app manifest to include my C# app's client id, adding this:

   "webApplicationInfo": {
   "id": "{my C# app's client id}",
   "applicationPermissions": [
   "TeamsActivity.Send"
   ]
   }
3. I zipped up my files again and uploaded the package to the [Teams admin center](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/).
4. I was then able to install the custom app I had uploaded to my Teams app.
5. After installing the app, I tried testing my C# app but neither the id nor externalid values were working for my "APP_ID", was getting the same exception as you mentioned.  So I opened [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), and found out the id using this query: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsApp (it will be a long string, not a GUID).

Once I used that id, everything worked.

From my understanding, the Teams app and your C# app are essentially 2 different registered apps that are tied together using the client id of your C# app, which I assume is just for authentication purposes.  I guess if you don't have your C# app's client id in the Teams app's manifest, it can't authenticate, which seemed to be my issue.  Also make sure your recipient has the app installed as that can also cause this exception.