# getting error while using sendActivityNotification graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using the below POST api.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/sendActivityNotification
```

```
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "text",
        "value": "Weekly Virtual Social",
        "webUrl": "{{team link}}"
    },
    "previewText": {
        "content": "It will be fun!"
    },
    "activityType": "eventCreated",
    "recipient": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.channelMembersNotificationRecipient",
        "teamId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        "channelId": "19:123456qwertyui....@thread.tacv2"
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Application with AAD App Id 'APP-ID' is
> not authorized to generate custom text notifications about
> '/beta/teams/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.sendActivityNotification'
> to the recipient. Ensure that the expected Teams app is installed in
> the target scope (user, team, or chat).

**Note:**

- I have a bot-based application, that is installed in the team in which I am sending notifications.
- The app ID matches with the App id in error.
- The app manifest contains `webApplication info`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application with AAD App Id is not authorized to generate notifications about \[...\] to the recipient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346794/application-with-aad-app-id-is-not-authorized-to-generate-notifications-about)

Comment: @gaurav - Could you please confirm if the the comment solved your issue?

Comment: did you added the `admin consent` for the `graph api` you are sending request to?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved?

Comment: The issue is resolved and will provide the answer below @Meghana-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

After searching found I need to include `applicatiopermission` in the `webApplicationInfo` JSON in the manifest file as below:

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "5xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx9",
    "resource": "api://5xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx9",
    "applicationPermissions": [,
      "TeamsActivity.Send.Group"
    ]
  }
```